# Is it appropriate to suggest tag synonyms on Meta?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently no tag synonyms on the Ubuntu StackExchange site, and only a few users with the required reputation. It seems unlikely that I will have enough reputation to suggest synonyms anytime soon through the [site feature](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=promotion&sort=info&pagesize=15) for that purpose. Is it appropriate to suggest them here?

I'm asking because I noticed [a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437/how-should-we-promote-ubuntu) today that had tags for "promotion" and "spread" which, as I understand their definitions, are synonyms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. We should.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem so. See [Tag synonym suggestions](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/184/18612) if you have tag synonyms you would like to suggest.