# Tag synonym suggestions

Tags: discussion, tags

> **For future suggestions, make a separate post so we can keep track of how well we are doing with tags, as well as facilitating discussion on a specific tag. Thanks**

I don't have enough reputation to suggest or vote on tag synonyms, but I've noticed some possible synonyms. I already posted one suggestion in a [separate question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/144/is-it-appropriate-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-on-meta) about whether I should suggest them here on meta, but I thought it would be useful to have a post just for suggested synonyms.

I'm not sure what an appropriate format is, but the [synonyms page](https://askubuntu.com/tags/synonyms) lists them in a table with master tag to the left of the synonym with a left facing arrow. Therefore, I will post my suggestions in the answers using the format "master < synonym"

Comment: [tag:recursion] < [tag:recursion]

Answer (score 14):

Everyone please feel free to add tag synonyms here if you're having a hard time getting a synonym pushed through:

### Tag Synonyms

- [package-management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/package-management) <- [packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/packages)
- [networking](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/networking) <- [connectivity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/connectivity) <- [connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/connection) <- [connections](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/connections)

### Meta or other worthless tags

- [software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software)
- [connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/connection)
- [application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/application)
- [freeze](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/freeze) and [error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/error)
- [missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/missing)
- [learn](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/learn)

Answer (score 1):

Another group which might have some overlaps:

- [package-management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/package-management)
- [package-manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/package-manager)
- [installer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installer)

Comment: Package Manager and Package Management are two different concepts. I agree that there will likely be overlap between installer and package-management

Comment: I always thought installer meant "either ubiquity or debian-installer, the program that installs ubuntu"