# Why separate "torrent" and "bittorrent" tags?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, asking-questions, tag-synonyms

Why do we have [torrent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/torrent) and [bittorrent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bittorrent) as separate tags on [main](http://askubuntu.com)?

Comment: bittorrent is a program a torrent is a filetype.

Comment: @Alvar Bittorrent is also a protocol, and a torrent is also a collection of one or more files transmitted together using that protocol. Furthermore, the program Bittorrent has been [proprietary for quite some time and no longer runs natively on Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_(software)), and there is no package for it in official Ubuntu software sources; it seems unlikely that [tag:bittorrent] is intended to refer to the application called Bittorrent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes people make tags and don't think about existing ones. We have an open question where you can lump in all the tag synonyms and the mods will look after them, feel free to add on:

- [Tag synonym suggestions](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/184/tag-synonym-suggestions)

Comment: Thanks; I've [posted](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/184/tag-synonym-suggestions/2071#2071).