# Tag synonyms needed

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed that there are two nearly-identical tags: [script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/script) and [scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/scripts). One should be made a synonym of the other, but I don't have enough rep to do so. Would someone else like to handle this?

Comment: I added it to the big list:

- http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/184/tag-synonym-suggestions