# Tag synonym request: [asterix] -> [asterisk]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The tag [asterix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/asterix) should really be a tag synonym of [asterisk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/asterisk).

Just so you understand why.

This guy, is [Asterix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix):

[image]

[Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) on the other hand is an open source PBX software.

Comment: Should be in http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/184/tag-synonym-suggestions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Done an done.

Here's a poem by Omar Khayyam to get the minimum character count.

> Dreaming when dawn's left Hand was in the sky
>   I heard a voice within the tavern cry,
>   "Awake, my little ones, and fill the cup
>   before life's liquor in its cup be dry."